# Binomial Process

Tags: probability

When defining a binomial process two of the conditions that define it are:

The probability of a success, p, must be fixed throughout the trials

The trials must be mutually independent.

What is the difference between these two conditions?

Comment: The first condition is about the distributions of the values of the process (the values of the process are identically distributed) and the second condition is about the dependence structure of the values of the process (the values of the process are mutually independent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider tossing a coin that gets heads with probability $p$. What is the probability of two heads in two tosses, $P(H_1H_2)$. Under the usual assumptions, $P(H_1H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2) = p^2$.

Suppose the probability of success is fixed, but the events are not independent. Then $P(H_1)=P(H_2)=p$ as before, but it's not true that $P(H_1H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2)$.

Now suppose the tosses are independent, but the success probability changes. Then it is true that $P(H_1H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2)$, but $P(H_1) \ne P(H_2)$.